# Typescript: _this2.onClick is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, typescript2.0, native-base

I use typescript for react-native development.
Here `List` and `ListItem` are from NativeBase and `ListItem` is like `TouchableOpacity` component.

```
...
public onClick = () => this.props.navigation.navigate("NextScreen");
public _renderRow = (item: any) {
    return (
        <ListItem onPress={() => this.onClick()}>
             ...
        </ListItem>
    );
}
public render() {
   return(
        <List
            dataArray={this.data}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
   );
}
```

When I click item, it shows following error.

> _this2.onClick is not a function. (In '_this2.onClick()', '_this2.onClick' is undefined)

I assume this is because `onClick()` function isn't bound to component class. Is the function bound automatically in typescript?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `bind` the method to the components class:

```js
public onClick() { 
  this.props.navigation.navigate("NextScreen"); 
}
public _renderRow(item: any) {
    return (
        <ListItem onPress={this.onClick}>
             ...
        </ListItem>
    );
}
public render() {
   return(
        <List
            dataArray={this.data}
            renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)} // <---- Here
        />
   );
}
```

Comment: That's strange. `this.onClick.bind(this)` isn't needed. Instead `this._renderRow.bind(this)` solved problem! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I will. please fix `this.onClick()`.

Comment: No, only `this.onClick` instead of `this.onClick()`